# Get data from serialized Java objects

Tags: java, deserialization

I have DB with a lot of data stored there as blobs. Those are basically binary serialized Java objects (not JSON or something easy to parse). AFAIK mostly array-like structures. I have the source code of this web app, but it's ancient and utterly broken, can't build app anymore because of missed dependencies and tools (also I have close to none knowledge of Java). Useful only to check logic it seems...

**Question is how to get stored data?** I'm not interested in objects itself, only in any meaningful data stored there, so converting it into JSON or similar would be fine. Preferably without programming in Java. Some library in PHP would be ideal.

It looks like [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) is right tool to use, but not clear how exactly to use it in the given situation.

UPD: Example of blob in question (in hex): `ACED0005737200136A6176612E7574696C2E41727261794C6973747881D21D99C7619D03000149000473697A6578700000000077040000000078`

UPD2: Previous sample actually is an empty ArrayList object, so another sample, not empty: `ACED0005737200116A6176612E7574696C2E486173684D61700507DAC1C31660D103000246000A6C6F6164466163746F724900097468726573686F6C6478703F400000000000107708000000000000000078`

It seems Node.js [java.io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/java.io) package does what's needed, but I'll look for better options for now.

UDP3: Second sample turns out to be empty HashSet. I had found non-empty samples too, all ArrayList or HashSet, java.io handles them well. Approach from xonya's answers should work, but demands more work compared to Node.js solution merely because of need to handle all types involved.

Comment: If the data is stored as deserialized Java objects you need to write some Java code to read it. Are you able to understand what Java classes are stored inside those arrays? Can you post one of these blobs as example? Gson can be useful for the next step (converting the deserialized Java objects in JSON structures).

Comment: @xonya It has non-printable characters, so I'm not sure how to show it. Like this: " �� sr java.util.ArrayListx����a� I sizexp    w    x        ". In hex ACED0005737200136A6176612E7574696C2E41727261794C6973747881D21D99C7619D03000149000473697A6578700000000077040000000078

Comment: Second example is an empty `HashMap`.

Comment: @xonya No, java.io gets this: {"$":{"loadFactor":0.75,"threshold":16},"$class":{"name":"java.util.HashMap","serialVersionUID":"362498820763181265","flags":3,"fields":[{"type":"F","name":"loadFactor"},{"type":"I","name":"threshold"}],"superClass":null},"_$":{}} Those fields names seem real ones. That's custom classes I've mentioned before, to store different types of data.

Comment: I think that's the output of Node.js library, that is inspecting the HashMap class. Have a look inside [HashMap source code](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#L140). You will find the same `serialVersionUID` and also those `loadFactor` and `threshold` fields.

Comment: @xonya My bad, I had to check other samples too. For now it seems most of those blobs are actually empty.

Answer (score 0):

First step is going to be to deserialize it to Java (Assuming that is the mechanism) using existing code.
Once you have done that then you can serialize it to whatever you want (JSON,XML,CSV, etc...).

The hardest part is figuring the code to deserialize the values stored. Also if the classes have different serialization Ids than original that may be impossible.

If you post some code with what you have tried you might be able to get some help here.

Comment: Making to build even stripped down code sure would be well beyond a simple question on SO... Also I haven't seen any UIDs in code, hence those likely are autogenerated and likely would be different (my IDE and tools are totally different ones from author's). Legacy app.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that there are a couple of Python projects attempting to do this (I didn't try them):

- [java-binary-deserializer](https://github.com/koutto/java-binary-deserializer)
- [python-javaobj](https://github.com/vbuell/python-javaobj)

Alternatively, you have to write a Java program that performs the deserialization. After that, you can convert the deserialized Java objects into JSON (for example using the Gson library you mentioned).

If the arrays contain instances of simple classes (like `Integer` or `String`) you would be able to do it as in the following minimal example (that uses the hex data you provided):

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.util.List;
// commons-codec library included just to parse the hex in the example
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String hexBlob = "ACED0005737200136A6176612E7574696C2E41727261794C6973747881D21D99C7619D03000149000473697A6578700000000077040000000078";

        byte[] bytes = Hex.decodeHex(hexBlob.toCharArray());

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        try (ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)) {
            ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
            List<Object> list = (List<Object>) objectInputStream.readObject();
            System.out.println(gson.toJson(list));
        }
    }
}
```

In this case it prints an empty array.

If the arrays contain classes defined by your project, things become more complicated.

For more information about this topic read [Introduction to Java Serialization](https://www.baeldung.com/java-serialization).

Comment: Thanks, I've checked Python libs, didn't work. Data in question is mostly consist from simple types, but some use custom classes like in second sample. I'm fine with amount of data java.io can get, I'll have to remap it anyway. Now it's just about better tool for a job.